# Is there a "queue widget" in swing?

Tags: swing

I'm trying to build a simple management system, and I would like to show the queue that stores all the jobs.
Is there a widget in swing that I can use to implement it?  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The most suitable Swing component for displaying a queue is probably a [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) or [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

How to get your data into the Swing component depends on how your queue is implemented.

Comment: I'm thinking of like a bar graph thing where there are blocks on the bar that can be clicked to get info about that block.

Comment: You could make custom cellrenderers in the list or table to do that.